# Verilog Mealy FSM with 1 module

Tags: verilog, fsm

I must write a verilog program for 1 mealy fsm. There are many techniques to write it. I'll show you 1 and i want to know if it works too(no need to mention other techniques, just say if that works or not and why!) here it is:

```
module MealyFsm(out,in,clk,rst);
  output out;
  input in,clk,rst;

  reg [1:0] q;

  always @(posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
    if (~rst) 
      q<=2'b00;
    else
      begin
        q[0]<=~q[0] &  q[1] &  x | ~q[0] &    x | q[1] &  x;
        q[1]<= q[1] & ~q[0] & ~x | ~q[1] & q[0] | q[0] & ~x;
      end
  end

  assign y = ~x & q[0] & ~q[1];

endmodule
```

PS. Im interested only for this technique, If its wrong please try tell me whats wrong in order to fix it

Comment: Please use a simulator to debug your programs.

Comment: well im using verilog in theoretical view of fsm.. I dont need the answer to cheat to exercise or something like that.. I can rewrite it easily using other techniques. I was just curious about this one and i cant find something related on verilog tutorials, digital design book or internet examples. If you can asnwer my question..     PS im working on net cafe and i cant download compiler and simulator..

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealy_machine)

> In the theory of computation, a Mealy machine is a finite-state
>   machine whose output values are determined both by its current state
>   and the current inputs.

Assuming that input `in`, has been typoed as `x` in the code, then does the module meet the definition?

You have some state `q`. and some output `y`. Your input `in or x` directly effects the output. So this meets the definition of a Mealy Machine.

NB: the logic is hard to follow and the function and flow of states is hard to see, there are much better ways of writing a FSM most of which are done in a single module.

Comment: well you are right about 'in'(its x in this example, i just wrote it fast and didnt notice i had named it 'in :p). as about the question I was just curious if that technique is correct too, because its too easy-fast to write when you have the equations for each D-flip-flip's next state. Otherwise i would have to write +1 module for the d-flip-flop definion or define some parameter variables(for the states) and use them in the always block to change between stats based on input and etc etc etc technices.

Comment: Anyway as i understood thats correct too but not the best way to do it because its hard to understand(to find the connections between stats) and that makes it harder to create the state transition graph . Ty for answering